# How do I make a JMS ObjectMessage for a Unit Test?

Tags: junit, jms, ejb, jmockit

I'm trying to write a unit test for an MDB. The goal of my test is to make sure that the logic in the MDB can identify the correct type of object in the `ObjectMessage` and process it. However, I can't figure out how to make an `ObjectMessage` so I can test it. I keep getting null pointer exceptions.

Here is my unit test:

```java
/**
 * Test of the logic in the MDB
 */
@RunWith(JMockit.class)
@ExtendWith(TimingExtension.class)
class MDBTest
{
    protected MyMDB mdb;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setup() throws NamingException, CreateHeaderException, DatatypeConfigurationException, PropertiesDataException
    {
        mdb = new MyMDB();
    }

    /**
     * Test the processing of the messages by the MDB
     */
    @Test
    void testReceivingMessage() throws JMSException, IOException
    {
        MyFirstObject testMsg = getTestMessage();
        ObjectMessage msg = null;
        Session session = null;
        
        new MockUp<ObjectMessage>()
        {
            @Mock
            public void $init()
            {
            }

            @Mock
            public Serializable getObject()
            {
                return testMsg;
            }
        };
        
        new MockUp<Session>()
        {
            @Mock
            public void $init()
            {
            }

            @Mock
            public ObjectMessage createObjectMessage(Serializable object)
            {
                return msg;
            }
        };
        
        // !!!! Null pointer here on Session !!!!
        ObjectMessage msgToSend = session.createObjectMessage(testMsg);
        
        mdb.onMessage(msgToSend);
        assertEquals(1, mdb.getNumMyFirstObjectMsgs());

    }

 
    /**
     * Create a Test Message
     *
     * @return the test message
     * @throws IOException
     */
    protected MyFirstObject getTestMessage) throws IOException
    {

        MyFirstObject myObj = new MyFirstObject();
        myObj.id = 0123;        
        myObj.description = "TestMessage";
        return myObj;

    }

}
```

I feel like I should be able to initialize `Session` somehow, but I need to do it without using an additional library like Mockrunner.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What are you trying to test here? End to end flow, message dequeue to consume?

Comment: @sonus21 I'm trying to test the logic for processing the messages. I want to test that it 1. Identifies the correct obect 2. Performs the correct actions on that object. In order to test this logic I need a test ObejectMessage I can pass in.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to address this in a different style. Provide a mock client, that will just mock the **right API**.

We should mock only a set of functions required for message retrieval and processing but that means we might have to provide a custom implementation for some of the APIs available in the EJB/JMS library. The mock client will have a function to push messages on a given topic/queue/channel, message can be simple String.

A simple implementation might look like this, in this other methods have been omitted for simplicity.

```
// JMSClientImpl is an implementation of Connection interface.

public class MyJmsTestClient extends JMSClientImpl{
    Map<String, String> channelToMessage = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    public Map<String, String> getMessageMap(){
        return channelToMessage;
    }
    public void enqueMessage(String channel, String message){
       channelToMessage.put(channe, message);
    }
    @Override
    public Session createSession(){
      return new MyTestSession(this);
    }
}
```

// A class that implements some of the methods from session interface

```
public MyTestSession extends SessionImpl{
   private MyJmsTestClient jmsClient;
   MyTestSession(MyJmsTestClient jmsClient){
      this.jmsClient = jmsClient;
   }
  // override methods that fetches messages from remote JMS
  // Here you can just return messages from MyJmsTestClient
  // override other necessary methods like ack/nack etc
  MessageConsumer createConsumer(Destination destination) throws JMSException{
     // returns a test consume
  }
}
```

A class that implements methods from MessageConsumer  interface

```
class TestMessageConsumer extends MessageConsumerImpl {
   private MyJmsTestClient jmsClient;
   private Destination destination;
   TestMessageConsumer(MyJmsTestClient jmsClient, Destination destination){
          this.jmsClient = jmsClient;
          this.destination = destination;
   }

   Message receive() throws JMSException{
    //return message from client
   }
}
```

There's no straight forward, you can see if there're any library that can provide you embedded JMS client feature.